Under what conditions do the Lie derivative and covariant derivative agree?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$ and suppose $\nabla$ is a connection. Of course the covariant derivative depends on the choice of $\nabla$ whereas the Lie derivative does not require any additional structure such as a connection. In general these two do not agree, but are there any conditions that can be placed on $\nabla$ so that for all $X$ and $Y$ we have $\mathcal{L}_XY = \nabla_X Y$?

Such a connection cannot exist. The expression $\nabla_X Y$ is tensorial in $X$, i.e., it depends only on the pointwise value of $X$. On the other hand, $\mathcal{L}_X Y$ is never tensorial in $X$. To see this, recall that $\mathcal{L}_X Y$ is equal to the Lie bracket $[X, Y]$. In coordinates, we have (using Einstein summation convention)
$$
[X, Y] = (X^j\partial_jY^i - Y^j\partial_jX^i)\partial_i.
$$
The right-hand side involves the derivatives of $X$, i.e., $\mathcal{L}_X Y$ depends on the first-order behavior of $X$ at each point. In particular, this shows $\mathcal{L}_XY$ is not tensorial in $X$.
